# Replace patterns using gsub and blocks

Tags: ruby, regex

When you have strings like this:

```
str = "john_1"
str = "joe_34"
str = "jack_54"
```

And you want to get all characters preceding the underscore, you can use split:

```
str.split("_")[0]
 => "john"
```

You can also achieve the same using matched groups and \1 \2 matchers:

```
str = "john_1"
str.gsub(/(.+)_.+/,'\1')
```

I am trying to understand what happens in the block better. From what I read, it replaces the matched group with the result of executing the block. But I don't see it behaving that way.

In the below example, if it is supposed to replace the matched group with the result of the block:

```
str = "john_1"
str.gsub(/.+(_.+)/) {|m| ""}
 => ""
```

Then why is the return value an empty string? The result should be "john" because only the underscore and all subsequent characters were matched and replaced with an empty string. What am I missing?

Comment: Two other ways, for `str = "john_1"`: 1.`str[/.*(?=_)/] #=> "john"`, `(?=_)` being a postive lookahead; and 2. `str[0...str.index('_')]
 => "john" `.

Comment: Because `m` matches the entire string. You want to convert the contents of capture group 1 to an empty string: To do that, change the capture group : `str.gsub(/(.+)_.*/) { $1 }` or (simpler) `str.gsub(/(.+)_.*/, '\1')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsub` replaces all occurrences of input pattern with the value of the result of the block.
Here `/.+(_.+)/` will match the whole string `john_1`, hence the whole string will be replaced with `""`

If you want to only match `_1` part with regex, here is one way to do it with regex lookahead

```
str.gsub(/(?=.+)(_.+)/, "")
```

Comment: why does /.+(_.+)/ match the whole string? The matcher is not the whole string. it is only _1 part.

Comment: With /.+(_.+)/ the whole string is matched, but only the _1 is "captured"
You can see it better at http://rubular.com/r/RYEPitk9g0